# AWS Polly TTS for Windows 10 SAPI - voices not appearing in control panel

Tags: text-to-speech, sapi, amazon-polly

I've followed this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/install-voice-plugin2.html), which shows how to install AWS Polly voices on Windows 10 for use with SAPI applications.

However, I cannot get any additional voices to appear in the Windows 10 voices control panel, or in the AWS Polly Player.

If I run the command `aws --profile polly-windows polly describe-voices` the list of voices appear in the CLI, but when running AWS Polly Player or looking in Windows control panel under voices, no voices appear.

Comment: The windows control panel lists Windows Media Foundation voices, which is a different subsystem than SAPI5. You need to use an application that supports SAPI. If you want to use Powershell [this script](https://gist.github.com/lselden/cde51ca2debdd7c7c16ea4abf621f8d5) *might* work

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me, you've probably installed the plugin first, before the command prompt settings.

Uninstall and reinstall the aws player to get the list of voices in the aws player.

Comment: Yes, just noticed it goes through a "installing voices" phase during install of PollyPlayer, so everything must be configured at that point.